# Rails: simple_form radio buttons to switch (zurb foundation)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, simple-form, form-helpers

I am trying to use the switch element from Zurb foundation on Rails radio buttons.

**I have this code:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @mymodel .... |f| %>

<%= f.input :active, as: :radio_buttons %>

<% end %>
```

Which generates a **yes** and **no** radio button.

I am now trying to implement the zurb foundation switch, since it looks nicer.

[Zurb Foundation Switch element](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html)

**Example code of a default switch:**

```
<div class="switch">
  <input id="x" name="switch-x" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="x" onclick="">Off</label>

  <input id="x1" name="switch-x" type="radio">
  <label for="x1" onclick="">On</label>

  <span></span>
</div>
```

**The Problem is, it looks like this:**

```
<div class="switch">
    <div class="input radio_buttons optional mymodel_active">
    <label class="radio_buttons optional">active</label>
    <span class="radio">
    <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="mymodel_active_true" name="mymodel[active]" type="radio" value="true">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="mymodel_active_true">Yes</label>   
    </span>
    <span class="radio">
    <input checked="checked" class="radio_buttons optional" id="mymodel_active_false" name="mymodel[active]" type="radio" value="false">
    <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="mymodel_active_false">No</label>
    </span>
    </div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Then I added: `, label: false ,:input_html => { :onclick => ' ' }` as attribute, to adjust to the example. It still won´t switch after the first time? I now have `onclick=""` on the input, but I need it on the label.

```
 <%= f.label :active , input_html: { :onclick => ' ' } %>
```

Will not work.

Anyone know the problem? Thanks

Comment: It was not possible for me to achieve this with rails helper functions. So I used plain HTML to build them, which was not "elegant".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use simple form custom wrappers https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers